# python3: name of the file which imports the current module?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

Suppose I have a python module called, say, `pymodule`, residing in a file called `pymodule.py`.

Furthermore, suppose `pymodule` is imported by a number of other python programs, for example, `program0.py`, `program1.py`, and `program2.py`.

Is there any code I could write within `pymodule.py` to determine at runtime the name of the file that it is imported into? In this example, we would end up with either `/path/to/program0.py`, `/path/to/program1.py`, or `/path/to/program2.py`, depending upon which of those three programs is running.

Of course, there could be a nested group of imports within which `pymodule` has been imported, and so in the general case, I'd ideally like to obtain this entire group of import ancestor file names at runtime.

Is there any way to do this in python3?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I figured it out. This code could reside in `pymodule.py` ...

```
# This is the "parent" of the current module.
# `sys._getframe(0)` would be `pymodule.py`.
f = sys._getframe(1)
while f is not None:
    print('filename: {}'.format(f.f_code.co_filename)
    f = f.f_back
```

It prints out the following if `/path/to/program0.py` is running ...

```
filename: <frozen importlib._bootstrap>
filename: <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>
filename: <frozen importlib._bootstrap>
filename: <frozen importlib._bootstrap>
filename: <frozen importlib._bootstrap>
filename: /path/to/program0.py
```

So, all I have to do is ignore the items which begin with `<frozen ...`, and I will get the ancestor file names. Here's a function that does it ...

```
def ancestor_importers():
    ancestors = []
    # Start with item number 2 here, because we're
    # inside of a function. Assume this function
    # resides at the top level of `pymodule`. If not,
    # the argument of sys._getframe(2) needs to be
    # adjusted accordingly.
    f = sys._getframe(2)
    while f is not None:
        fn = f.f_code.co_filename
        if not fn.startswith('<frozen '):
            ancestors.append(fn)
        f = f.f_back
    return ancestors
```